# How do I install the correct version of windbg?

Tags: windbg, intel

I have intel 2500k processor yet winsdk installed amd64 version for me. I can't seem to find a way to download intel64 version anywhere nor change the installation option. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

amd64 is the 64bit version of x86. IA64 is the Itanium version. You want the amd64 version for a 2500K.

Answer (score 1):

Read this to learn why AMD64, Intel64, x64 are compatible terms.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64